# Show Desktop command not working

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon

I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 and have installed cinnamon Desktop. 
I have set `Ctrl+Supr+D` as shortcut to show desktop [Hide all normal windows].

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion on where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is some other action bound with this combination. I hope you have verified the shortcuts from Settings.